# How to create Dom objects parsing an XML with Stax

Tags: java, stax, staxmate

I have some difficulties to parse an XML using Stax in order to create org.w3c.dom.Document objects for parts of the XML tree.

Ex.:
<root>
<children>
<child>child 1</child>
<child>child 2</child>
<child>child 3</child>
</children>
</root>
=> I would like to create 3 DOM objects for each <child> node.

I tried to do this using Staxmate and DomConverter but I have a problem ...

My test project only depends on :

- stax2-api-3.0.3.jar
- staxmate-2.0.0.jar
- jdk 1.6.0_21

2 tests :

- Test 1 that works perfectly

```
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("demo.xml");
    XMLStreamReader sr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(in);
    Document doc = new DOMConverter().buildDocument(sr);
    in.close();
```

- Test 2 that throws a HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR exception :

```
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("demo.xml");
    XMLStreamReader sr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(in);
    while (sr.hasNext()) {

      sr.next();
      switch (sr.getEventType()) {
        case XMLStreamReader.START_ELEMENT:
          Document doc = new DOMConverter().buildDocument(sr);
      }
    }
    in.close();
```

```
    org.w3c.dom.DOMException: HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: An attempt was made to insert a node where it is not permitted.
          at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.CoreDocumentImpl.insertBefore(CoreDocumentImpl.java:391)
          at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.NodeImpl.appendChild(NodeImpl.java:235)
          at org.codehaus.staxmate.dom.DOMConverter._build(DOMConverter.java:292)
          at org.codehaus.staxmate.dom.DOMConverter.buildDocument(DOMConverter.java:171)
          at org.codehaus.staxmate.dom.DOMConverter.buildDocument(DOMConverter.java:152)
          at org.codehaus.staxmate.dom.DOMConverter.buildDocument(DOMConverter.java:131)
          at com.staxmatetest.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Could you help me please ?

Best regards,
Guillaume LEFEBVRE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Staxmate release 2.0.1 (available at http://wiki.fasterxml.com/StaxMateDownload) solved this issue.

Thank you StaxMan !

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/STAXMATE-39... :-)